# How to backup & restore data using python for OpenERP?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, odoo

I have some problem for backup and restore database using python for OpenERP.
I would like to backup sale_order table and related tables for this. But... I don't know how to restore that backup file because there have some related keys (foreign key) vice visa..

e.g.
I have backup file for sale_order that related tables like this:

```
insert into sale_order ....
insert into sale_order_line ...
```

that time, I have error for sale_order_line because sale_order_line have foreign key for procurement_order's id ... so I changed

```
insert into sale_order...
insert into procurement_order...
insert into sale_order_line...
```

but ... I've an error at procurement_order for  foreign key for stock_move's id... so I changed again...

```
insert into sale_order...
insert into stock_move...
insert into procurement_order...
insert into sale_order_line...
```

but... it's still not OK :( because stock_move have foreign key of sale_order_line'id... 
I don't know how to do...

That's why... What is the best solution for this backup and restore for that case?
If you have any idea, please give me.
Thanks.

Comment: Why did you decide not to use pg_backup?

Comment: Because the customer want to backup & restore data from the OpenERP UI. They'd the some shop that didn't get internet network so that they want to upload sale/pos data of this shop to the main database.

Comment: So it's not backup + restore, it's export + import.

Comment: yeah! It's export + import. How can I do for that case. If you don't mind, please explain me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without providing schemas for the tables with their foreign keys it's difficult to provide accurate help.

It *is* possible to generate data that defies a simple batch insert. You can leave a FK null and set it after dependencies are added.

So - you probably want to read up about deferring constraints and disabling foreign keys. Start [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/populate.html) for a quick overview and work out from there.

Oh - and are you sure you won't have any problems with overlapping primary keys from this setup?

Comment: Yeah! I have problems with overlapping primary keys. I don't know how to solve this problem. I've no experience for that database export/import by any programming language.

Comment: OK - first thing you need to do is take yourself off to the OpenERP support lists/groups and discuss with them. You'll need to know *exactly* what you're doing with this and allow for more effort any time you want to upgrade OpenERP. It is almost certainly simpler/cheaper to install internet access at the shop.